# Do.com OAuth2 won't give response code

Tags: http, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to interface with Do.com's API, which uses OAuth2, but I can't get a redirect/response code.

I have my "identifier" and "secret" from Do.com and am trying to follow the [Do.com authentication instructions](https://do.com/developers/authentication) by making the initial request using this url:

```
https://www.do.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=(my "identifier")
```

When I do that, I'm taken to the login page, and once logged in, I get prompted to grant permission. Once I click "allow", I get taken to this error page:

[image: do.com "Something went wrong..." error page]

I thought that this might have to do with the redirect url or the referrer. When I initially set requested the id and secret, I also had to provide a redirect url. So, at the location of this redirect URL, I made a simple page with just the link on it and used that to initiate the request (so that the referer could be the same as the redirect url), but I get the same result

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.do.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=(my "identifier")">Authorize</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to OAuth2, so I hope I'm just overlooking something here. I've tried contacting the Do.com support but haven't received a response.

Comment: Hey @netinept, I work at Do.com. Let me take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with our OAuth2 webflow implementation for the case when the redirect_uri is omitted. This has since been fixed as of Oct 8th, 2013 4:00PM PST.

Thanks for the report @netinept